# how to use mix two RDD with python

Tags: apache-spark, join, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have the following two RDDs,the first one is:

```python
training2 = training.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1],x[2])))
training2.collect()

#[(u'1', (u'4298118681424644510', u'7686695')),
# (u'1', (u'4860571499428580850', u'21560664')), 
# (u'1', (u'9704320783495875564', u'21748480')),
# (u'1', (u'13677630321509009335', u'3517124')),
```

and the second one is:

```python
user_id2 = user_id.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1],x[2])))
user_id2.collect()

#[(u'1', (u'1', u'5')),
# (u'2', (u'2', u'3')),
# (u'3', (u'1', u'5')),
# (u'4', (u'1', u'3')),
# (u'5', (u'2', u'1')),
```

In both RDD the parameter `u'1',u'2'...` indicates de user id, so I need to mix both RDD by key, the output must combinate for every key be something like this:

`u'1', (u'1', u'5', u'4298118681424644510', u'7686695')`

Comment: You can convert both rdds to a spark `DataFrame` using `rdd.toDF()`, and then use `join()` to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

How'about add two rdd and use `aggregateByKey(self, zeroValue, seqFunc, combFunc, numPartitions=None)`

you can also use `reduceByKey` or `groupByKey`

for example

```
zero_value=set()
def seq_op(x, y) :
    x.add(y)
    return x

def comb_op(x, y) :
    return x.union(y)

numbers = sc.parallelize([0,0,1,2,5,4,5,5,5]).map(lambda x : ["Even" if (x % 2 == 0) else "Odd", x])
numbers.collect()

numbers.aggregateByKey(zero_value, seq_op, comb_op).collect()
# results looks like [("Even", {0, 2, 4,}), ....]
```